# How to use 2 controllers in a game (Python)

Tags: python, controller, pygame

We want to create a game with 2 players and 2 controllers with Python (something like a Street Fighter). We have a problem, we don't know how to separate the 2 controllers.

When we use 1 controller to move or attack with 1 character, the other character is moving too.

Here is the code:

```
def usecontroller():   
    pygame.init()
    global instanceFenetrePause
    for i in range(0,pygame.joystick.get_count()):
        vr.listeJoysticks.append(pygame.joystick.Joystick(i))
        vr.listeJoysticks[-1].init() 

    while vr.loopGestionClavier :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
                instanceFenetrePause.affichage_fenetre()
            if vr.loopJeu :
                for x in range(0,len(vr.listeJoysticks)) :
                    if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN :
                        if event.button == 0 :
                            print ('command0')
                        if event.button == 1 :
                            print ('command1')
                        if event.button == 2 :
                            print ('command2')
                        if event.button == 3 :
                            print ('command3')
                        if event.button == 4 :
                            print ('command4')
                        if event.button == 5 :
                            print ('command5')
                        if event.button == 7 :
                            instanceFenetrePause.affichage_fenetre()
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look through the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) shows that all the joystick events include an attribute `event.joy` which should refer to which joystick created the event. Then simply use an `if` statement or some other control logic to determine which character should move. I am not familiar enough with pygame to know what the value of `event.joy` will be, but I suspect it will be the same numeric index as would be passed to `pygame.joystick.Joystick`.

For example using your code above:

```
if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN :
    if event.button == 0 :
        if event.joy == 0:
            print('player 1, command0')
        elif event.joy == 1:
            print('player 2, command0')

    if event.button == 1 :
        if event.joy == 0:
            print('player 1, command1')
        elif event.joy == 1:
            print('player 2, command1')
        print ('command1')
```

This of course will probably need to be modified to handle an arbitrary joystick index, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

As for example ...

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
textPrint = TextPrint()
player1 = {'width' : 40, 'height' : 40, 'velocity' : 5, 'color' : (0, 200, 255), 'x' : 50, 'y' : 50}
player2 = {'width' : 40, 'height' : 40, 'velocity' : 5, 'color' : (200, 200, 255), 'x' : 50, 'y' : 50}
run = True
while run:
    #
    # EVENT PROCESSING STEP
    #
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close.
            run = False # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            run = False 
    #
    # DRAWING STEP
    #
    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()
    # Get count of joysticks
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()
    textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of joysticks: {}".format(joystick_count))

    if joystick_count >= 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, player1['color'], (player1['x'], player1['y'], player1['width'], player1['height']))
        joystick1 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        if joystick1.get_axis(0) and joystick1.get_axis(0) < -0.2:
            player1['x'] -= player1['velocity']
        if joystick1.get_axis(0) and joystick1.get_axis(0) > 0.2:
            player1['x'] += player1['velocity']
        if joystick1.get_axis(1) and joystick1.get_axis(1) < -0.2:
            player1['y'] -= player1['velocity']
        if joystick1.get_axis(1) and joystick1.get_axis(1) > 0.2:
            player1['y'] += player1['velocity']

    if joystick_count > 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, player2['color'], (player2['x'], player2['y'], player2['width'], player2['height']))
        joystick2 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1)
        if joystick2.get_axis(0) and joystick2.get_axis(0) < -0.2:
            player2['x'] -= player2['velocity']
        if joystick2.get_axis(0) and joystick2.get_axis(0) > 0.2:
            player2['x'] += player2['velocity']
        if joystick2.get_axis(1) and joystick2.get_axis(1) < -0.2:
            player2['y'] -= player2['velocity']
        if joystick2.get_axis(1) and joystick2.get_axis(1) > 0.2:
            player2['y'] += player2['velocity']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).